# ipmitool error - how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, ipmitool

ipmitool previously worked on this system, but since a reboot it gives this error.

what does the error mean?
why did the reboot break it?

```
root@zebra:~# ipmitool power status
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
```

```
root@zebra:~# lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the driver:

```
modprobe ipmi_devintf
```

This also will load the `ipmi_si` module too. Note `dmesg` output afterwards: it should mention the IPMI interface was found and device node `/dev/ipmi0` (or something like this) should appear.

If it works, add it to some file in the `/etc/modules-load.d/` to auto-load on boot.

Comment: made no difference

Comment: So well, what is in `lsmod` and what was in `dmesg` when the driver was loaded? And, what is your motherboard? Is the BMC still available over the network (its dedicated interface)? What are boot time initialization messages? (I saw how the BMC in the SuperMicro motherboard died. Be prepared — that happens.)